# How to acess an service from another machine unsing rancher-server?

Tags: docker, networking, rancher

I'm trying to create a docker server using rancher on local network ( with many machines, some linux, some windows ). I had installed rancher-server, created a host, added an API to test and created a load balancer to registry this API. Locally, works fine, i can acess the API container like : "http://test.172.17.0.4.xip.io:3000/", but in others machines in my network, i cant acess..

PS:
`test` -> API name
`172.17.0.4` -> Ip of HOST machine docker ( with rancher-agent )
`xip.io` -> public wildcard DNS ( see more in : http://xip.io/ )
`3000` -> API port mapped in load balancer

I'vd tryed to change network of the container in rancher UI, didn't work, i read some things about create a docker network, but i'm a bit confused, cuz docker create a defaut netdocker, docker0, is an bridge network.. I'm a little lay in network matters.

EDIT:
I created macvlan using docker network, and now i can ping to my container using others machines, but now, i my container dont have  internet connection to download things.

`docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=172.16.108.0/26 --gateway=172.16.108.1 -o macvlan_mode=bridge -o parent=enp1s0 rancher`

and tried to run a container in this network

EDIT2:
This `ifconfig` output

docker0: flags=4099  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:79:4f:fc:66  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp1s0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.108.1  netmask 255.255.255.192  broadcast 172.16.108.63
        inet6 fe80::593f:24d0:31f2:4fd8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether d0:94:66:a5:29:8f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1251  bytes 1024069 (1000.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 5  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 980  bytes 157904 (154.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Loopback Local)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

EDIT3: 
I tried to specify the ip adress passing the flag --address when start rancher and/or the host, and the result are the same: `unknown flag: --address` the commands i tried to do are:

`docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped --address 172.16.108.63 -p 8080:8080 rancher/server`

To start rancher server. I tried with macvlan too

`docker run --privileged --name some-docker1 --address 172.16.108.63 -d docker:stable-dind`

To start rancher machine ( to be the future host )

And i tried the same command above, but without the --address. Then, attached in shell of the container, i tried to create the host

`docker run -e CATTLE_AGENT_IP="172.17.0.3"  --rm --privileged --address 172.16.108.63  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /var/lib/rancher:/var/lib/rancher ran
cher/agent:v1.2.11 http://172.17.0.2:8080/v1/scripts/3FA0E7B767770264BCAD:1546214400000:P9NfsauqyhZpoeIBgGyCZIHkKtE`

The results are the same..

RESUME:
I'm trying to create a rancher-server in my local network to access the applications in my load balancer from other machines in the same network.

Comment: You need to use the public IP address of the host (or the private IP address that's accessible on the network).

Comment: Right, and you can tell me, how i do it ?

Comment: I do not know what the IP address of your host is. You can try `ip addr` of `ifconfig` if running a linux host and check for the IP address of the network interface. Something like `eth0` or `ens1` etc.

Comment: Usually when you get the xip URL, it should have the IP address of the host. Not sure what's happening in your setup.

Comment: Are you running Rancher Server and the Rancher Agent on the same host?

Comment: Yeah, i create a container with rancher server then a container with rancher agent

Comment: Please check the edited answer and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit 2: One needs to specify the IP address of the host being added using CATTLE_AGENT_IP. I got the versions wrong in the previous edit.

Edit 1:

When using the same host for running both the rancher server and the agent image, it's important to specify the IP address of the host using the flag `--address <IP address>`. Otherwise, the auto detected IP address would be incorrect.

In your case, you need to specify `--address 172.16.108.63` when registering the host.

Then xip address generated would reflect the correct IP address.

====

Here is one way to be able to access your application from outside the cluster. This involves use of Ingress. (Check here for more information: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

Step 1: Create a deployment (change the image and customize other options according to your needs)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: app1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: app1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app1
        image: leodotcloud/swiss-army-knife
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
        env:
        - name: NATO_ALPHABET
          value: "a"
```

Step 2: Create a service (One can directly create the ingress, but I like to keep things segregated)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: access-app1
  name: access-app1
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    name: app1
```

Step 3: Create Ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-app1
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /app1
        backend:
          serviceName: access-app1
          servicePort: 80
```

Now your application will be available at `http://<HOST_IP_ADDRESS>/app1`

Comment: I think you misundertood my problem, i edited `EDIT` and `EDIT2`, can you read them again ? =)

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help so far. I wrote EDIT3 to show the results of your suggestion, I also wrote the RESUME to try to keep our focus =)

Comment: You mentioned xip.io stuff, I thought you were using Rancher 2.x version. Looking at your docker run command, I realized you are using 1.6.x version. `--address` is not for 1.6.x version. You need to use CATTLE_AGENT_IP=172.16.108.63 for 1.6.x version.

Comment: Okay, now i can access my app's in my rancher from another machines using 172.16.108.2.xip.io:<app-port>. i will accept your answer, but let me make another quick question, sometimes my ip (172.16.108.2) changes, which is the easy way to fix it ?

Comment: You might have to create a script which monitors your IP address every few seconds/minutes, and once a change is detected, redeploy the agent container. But the Ingress URL might not change (I haven't tried this scenario myself). TBH, this is really not a normal/general use case :) ... can you not request for a static IP for your machine?

Comment: I'll try to do that, tnxs for the time =)